# Bounded away sequence implications

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Consider the sequence $\{\sqrt{n}|a_n-a|\}_n$ where $a_n, a \in \mathbb{R}$. Assume $\{\sqrt{n}|a_n-a|\}_n$ is bounded away from $0$ and $\infty$. Is this **equivalent** to or **sufficient** or **necessary** for

(1) $|a_n-a|=\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}$ for some $0<h<\infty$?

(2) $|a_n-a|\in O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$?

Answer (score 0):

Your sequences is bounded away from zero if and only if
\begin{equation}
\exists\, C_1> 0 \:  \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \, : \: C_1 \leq \sqrt{n} |a-a_n|. 
\end{equation}
This condition is necessary, but not sufficient for condition (1).

Your sequences is bounded from above (i.e. away from infinity) if and only if
\begin{equation}
\exists\, C_2 \ge 0 \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \: : \: \sqrt{n} |a-a_n| \leq C_2.
\end{equation}
This condition is equivalent to condition (2), which is really the statement 
\begin{equation}
\exists\, C \ge 0 \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \: : \: |a-a_n| \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just to be sure: (A) (1) implies bounded away from $0$ but not bounded away from $\infty$; (B) (2) is equivalent to bounded away from $\infty$ but not to bounded away from $0$. Correct?

Comment: Actually, $|a_n-a|=\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}$ doesn't mean $|a_n-a|=O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$? hence, doesn't it also imply that $\sqrt{n}|a_n-a|$ is bounded away from $\infty$?